# How can I account for "," and "." when ensuring a String is a valid double?

Tags: java

I'm trying to ensure that a given string is a valid double. Most answers to this sort of question suggest using `Double.parseDouble(inputString)`. However this isn't as robust as I'd hope. For instance if I enter a String such as *"1one"* `Double.parseDouble("1one")` will output "1" as opposed to returning an exception for an invalid double.

I've tried to get around this by iterating over the string and ensuring that every number is a digit:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        previousChar = number.charAt(i);

        if (!Character.isDigit(number.charAt(i))
                && number.charAt(i) != '.' 
                                    && number.charAt(i) != ',') {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But for cases such as "20..02" or "20,,02" this will simply return 20. I was wondering what the best way to account for cases such as these would be.

Comment: Check if there's only digits and only one or zero `,` or `.` not in the end of the String?

Comment: regular expression to validate it?

Comment: Are you sure `parseDouble` worked for `1one`?

Comment: I'm sure there are (plenty?) libraries for this.

Comment: You need a regular expression here, because even the commas must be at very specific places, and the dot can only appear once

Comment: Are you opposed to doing try catch on Double.parseDouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Depending on the users, you may need to be careful of differences between locales. Some places use `,` as a thousand separator others as a decimal point. You can find the locale-specific value using:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char decimalSeparator = symbols.getDecimalSeparator();
```

I would suggest writing a regular expression for your exact requirement rather than doing the matching manually. Remember to escape `.` if you want it to match `.` and not "any character".

Alternatively, you may be able to use `parseDouble` which does seem to throw an exception for `"1one"` after all:

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("1one"));
```

For me, it produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1one"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Validator framework and use the [DoubleValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DoubleValidator.html) from [commons-validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/).

```
DoubleValidator validator = DoubleValidator.getInstance();
validator.validate("1one");
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings to doubles is fraught with danger. For example, in France, 1,234 is a number just a little greater than 1. They use `.` to separate round thousands and `,` to denote the start of the decimal portion.

The best way to check if a string is a valid number is to use `NumberFormat` to attempt to parse it and treat any exceptions thrown as an indication that the string is not a valid number. `NumberFormat` allows you to associate a *locale*:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH/*for example*/);
double myNumber = nf.parse(myString); /*will throw an exception if not valid*/
```

Comment: This won't throw an exception for "1one"

Answer (score -1):

I would use `Double.parseDouble`, because, contrary to what you believe, it does throw a `NumberFormatException` for `1one`.

```
public class k {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
      double d = Double.parseDouble("1one");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1one"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at k.main(k.java:3)
```

If I wanted to allow both `,` and `.` and not just the decimal point specified by the locale, I would `replace` any `,` and  `.` with the locale specified decmial point.

Answer (score -2):

Using a simple regex, you can check if it contains any non numerical characters like so:

```
String input = "1one2";
String numerical = input.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
if (input.equals(numerical)) // If you remove all non numbers, still the same string
```

After which you can parse it for a double.